# cron script needs conditional to run

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I have two python scripts that Im trying to run on my server
I currently have process_one running through a cron job every five minutes I want to add the second script to the cron job.

I was told by the freelancer that both programs can run automatically by writing a shell script. If process_one generates data in its output_folder (i.e.
process_two's input_folder) then it will return system status "0" (OK) to the operating system, otherwise it returns a
ERROR signal - even in the case of "no errors, yet nothing new produced".
Im at a loss Ive never written shell scripts before. Im looking on here and else where but I dont know how to write this. Any help would be appreciated

```
/path/to process1/process_one && /path/to process2/process_two
```

Comment: Did that not work? Why not?

Comment: well that is how I want it written in cron so that they both execute, but process 2 is dependent on process one getting new data. Everyday process one checks and downloads new data if available, process two takes that data and creates a new file from it, but we only want that to run if process one found new data, currently with that command it tries to execute process_two even when there is no new data.

Comment: `process_one && process_two` will only run `process_two` if `process_one` returns success. If you believe you're seeing `process_two` run regardless, then the problem is not with the `&&` but with your assumption about what `process_one` returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have for the cron job is correct, process one will run and if successful process_two will run.  The only thing that is missing is for process_two to check for new data in the process_one output directory before it runs.

I would suggest that you use a few lines at the top of process_two python script to check for recent data and exit if not found.  Either you can modify the python script itself to do this, or write a bash wrapper as process_two that simply calls the python script after checking for recent data.

**py**

```
import os.path, time
fileCreation = os.path.getctime(filePath)
now = time.time()
fivemin_ago = now - 300
if fileCreation < fivemin_ago:
    sys.exit "data was older than five minutes"
```

**bash**

```
NOW=$(date +%s)
MODIFIED=$(date -d "$(stat FILEPATH | grep Modify | awk '{print $2" "$3}')" +%s)
if [ $NOW -gt $[$MODIFIED+300] ];then
    echo "data was older than five minutes"
    exit 1
else
    process_two.py
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way will make a third file where you can call the first script and get the return after the return you run or not the second script, it will be something like.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
variable=$(download "something")
if [-f "../path/your/file.pdf" ]; then
   run here your second command // if file exists run it
fi
```